# How to Curl Kibana Dashboard with GET Response to Find All Dashboard IDs and/or Dashboard Content

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, kibana

So I am trying to automate the scrape of our internal Kibana Dashboards from within our environments for information gathering purposes. I have looked through the following link, but Elasticsearch doesn't seem to really provide good examples of what I am trying to do or accomplish here. Several constraints I have: 1. the commands must be in BASH, 2. I cannot use any compiler such as Python and the Requests and/or Beautifulsoup modules to grab the information and parse it.

Here is my Dilemma:
I log in to the Kibana Dashboard:

Some http://<IP_ADDRESS>:5601/app/kibana#/dashboards?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-1h,mode:quick,to:now))

It will look like this if I am properly tunneled into the environment.

[image]

There are three dashboards that I want to collect:

1. API RESPONSES
2. Logs
3. Notifications

The example curl command I am using is as follows to scrape the dashboards:

```sh
curl -s http://<IP_ADDRESS>:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/API\ RESPONSES
curl -s http://<IP_ADDRESS>:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/logs
curl -s http://<IP_ADDRESS>:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/notifications
```

Now the [Elasticsearch Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#get-source-filtering) mentions something of a Dashboard ID, to which I cannot see it unless I open a webpage and use the inspect tool on a particular element I am sending the GET request to. I am trying to accomplish that by curling the main dashboard page:

```
curl -s http://<IP_ADDRESS>:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/_search?pretty
```

My output will return an HTML output, but it doesn't seem to change and I cannot properly acquire the Dashboards without knowing the Dashboard ID. Furthermore, I am trying to see what dashboards are available and scrape all of them depending on what a person has set up within the environment so it's important that this process is dynamic. My eventual and ultimate goals are to get:

1. Dashboard IDs Available
2. Scrape the Dashboards by IDs

Basically I want to curl this output to get the return JSON.
[image]
[image]

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, I was curling the wrong location.
I needed to curl the VIP and port 9200 for the Kibana Index to pull in the available dashboards.

```sh
rbarrett@cfg01:~$ curl -s http://<IP_ADDRESS>:9200/.kibana/dashboard/_search?pretty
{
  "took" : 15,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : ".kibana",
        "_type" : "dashboard",
        "_id" : "logs",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "",
          "hits" : 0,
          "kibanaSavedObjectMeta" : {
            "searchSourceJSON" : "{\"filter\":[{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}}}]}"
          },
          "optionsJSON" : "{\"darkTheme\":true}",
          "panelsJSON" : "[{\"col\":1,\"columns\":[\"Hostname\",\"Logger\",\"programname\",\"severity_label\",\"Payload\",\"environment_label\"],\"id\":\"search-logs\",\"panelIndex\":5,\"row\":13,\"size_x\":12,\"size_y\":12,\"sort\":[\"Timestamp\",\"desc\"],\"type\":\"search\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"NUMBER-OF-LOG-MESSAGES-PER-SEVERITY\",\"panelIndex\":7,\"row\":9,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"TOP-10-PROGRAMS\",\"panelIndex\":9,\"row\":5,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"LOG-MESSAGES-OVER-TIME-PER-SOURCE\",\"panelIndex\":10,\"row\":1,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"TOP-10-HOSTS\",\"panelIndex\":11,\"row\":9,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"TOP-10-SOURCES\",\"panelIndex\":14,\"row\":5,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"LOG-MESSAGES-OVER-TIME-PER-SEVERITY\",\"panelIndex\":16,\"row\":1,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"}]",
          "timeFrom" : "now-1h",
          "timeRestore" : true,
          "timeTo" : "now",
          "title" : "Logs",
          "uiStateJSON" : "{\"P-10\":{\"vis\":{\"legendOpen\":true}},\"P-11\":{\"vis\":{\"colors\":{\"Count\":\"#629E51\"},\"legendOpen\":true}},\"P-12\":{\"spy\":{\"mode\":{\"fill\":false,\"name\":null}},\"vis\":{\"colors\":{\"Count\":\"#2F575E\"},\"legendOpen\":false}},\"P-14\":{\"vis\":{\"legendOpen\":true}},\"P-7\":{\"vis\":{\"legendOpen\":false}},\"P-9\":{\"vis\":{\"colors\":{\"Count\":\"#99440A\"},\"legendOpen\":true}}}",
          "version" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : ".kibana",
        "_type" : "dashboard",
        "_id" : "notifications",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "",
          "hits" : 0,
          "kibanaSavedObjectMeta" : {
            "searchSourceJSON" : "{\"filter\":[{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}}}]}"
          },
          "optionsJSON" : "{\"darkTheme\":true}",
          "panelsJSON" : "[{\"col\":1,\"columns\":[\"Logger\",\"publisher\",\"severity_label\",\"event_type\",\"old_state\",\"old_task_state\",\"state\",\"new_task_state\",\"environment_label\",\"display_name\"],\"id\":\"search-notifications\",\"panelIndex\":1,\"row\":14,\"size_x\":12,\"size_y\":11,\"sort\":[\"Timestamp\",\"desc\"],\"type\":\"search\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"NOTIFICATIONS-OVER-TIME-PER-SOURCE\",\"panelIndex\":2,\"row\":1,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"NOTIFICATIONS-OVER-TIME-PER-SEVERITY\",\"panelIndex\":3,\"row\":1,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"EVENT-TYPE-BREAKDOWN\",\"panelIndex\":4,\"row\":5,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":5,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"SOURCE-BREAKDOWN\",\"panelIndex\":5,\"row\":5,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":5,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"HOST-BREAKDOWN\",\"panelIndex\":6,\"row\":10,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"NOTIFICATIONS-PER-SEVERITY\",\"panelIndex\":7,\"row\":10,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":4,\"type\":\"visualization\"}]",
          "timeFrom" : "now-1h",
          "timeRestore" : true,
          "timeTo" : "now",
          "title" : "Notifications",
          "uiStateJSON" : "{\"P-4\":{\"vis\":{\"legendOpen\":true}},\"P-7\":{\"vis\":{\"legendOpen\":false}}}",
          "version" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Afterwhich I was able to pull out the existing IDs with JQ:

Comment: You can also use Kibana's APi rather that Elasticsearch API to query for dashboards and visualizations.

Comment: @skap a link showing how to get started would be nice. I couldn't figure out which of the many APIs I needed to access (the Document API?), or the practicalities of how to do it (what's the URL? etc.).